# Changing the position of coordinate points randomly in a graph using python

Tags: python, graph, coordinates

I have a dataframe of 16 coordinate points.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {'x': [-0.3162277660168379967, -0.3162277660168379967, -0.9486832980505139901, 0.3162277660168379967, 0.9486832980505139901, -0.3162277660168379967, -0.3162277660168379967, -0.9486832980505139901, 0.9486832980505139901, 0.3162277660168379967, 0.3162277660168379967, 0.3162277660168379967, 0.9486832980505139901, -0.9486832980505139901, -0.9486832980505139901, 0.9486832980505139901],
        'y': [-0.9486832980505139901, 0.3162277660168379967, 0.9486832980505139901, 0.3162277660168379967, -0.3162277660168379967, 0.9486832980505139901, -0.3162277660168379967, -0.3162277660168379967, 0.3162277660168379967, -0.9486832980505139901, -0.3162277660168379967, 0.9486832980505139901, -0.9486832980505139901, 0.3162277660168379967, -0.9486832980505139901, 0.9486832980505139901]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
plt.show()
```

Now I want to randomly move their position from the original points (considered as noise in case of constellation diagram in wireless communications).  Some of the new positions should be close to the their original one and rest of them should be in between two original points.
Adding or subtracting to the original points only shift to specific direction not in random direction. How can I do that?

Comment: A few things: 1) Can you give examples of what would be valid randomizations? Having a hard time interpreting what you're hoping to do. Maybe a drawing would be helpful. 2) There's all sorts of ways to execute your desire to "randomly move" the points. It's likely that the uniform distribution would do you well (from `random` module).

Comment: For example, first coordinate point (-0.316,-0.948) from my DF, would be shifted to (-0.216, -0.848) or (-0.316, -0.648) position. So, it could be said that it has shifted 20 or 30% randomly from their origin. The same  type of shifting should be done for every other coordinate points. I hope, i've cleared myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're hoping to do, but I hope that this will get you started. I'm not using `pandas` below, but you easily could change the code below to do so.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import uniform, seed

data = {"x": [1, 9, 5, 8, 2], "y": [5, 1, 5, 2, 7]}
lower, upper = 0.7, 1.3 # allows for data to be changed by -30% to 30%
seed(100) # makes output the same every time, can change value to any number

# make randomized data
randomized_data = {}
for variable, value_lst in data.items():
    new_lst = []
    for value in value_lst:
        new_random_value = uniform(lower, upper) * value
        new_lst.append(new_random_value)
    randomized_data[variable] = new_lst


# this for loop is not necessary, just to help clarify answer in output graph
for i in range(len(data["x"])):
    points_x_vals = data["x"][i], randomized_data["x"][i]
    points_y_vals = data["y"][i], randomized_data["y"][i]
    plt.plot(points_x_vals, points_y_vals, "black")

# actual plotting of data
plt.scatter(data["x"], data["y"], label="original data")
plt.scatter(randomized_data["x"], randomized_data["y"], label="\"randomized\" data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Another question. what modification do I need to do, if I randomized only last two rows and the upper rows remains unchanged of this dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by "rows"? Is that points? Regardless, I hope you're understanding what is occurring in the code in my answer. If not, it would be good to do some research. I have full confidence that you would find a way to answer your question. Stack Overflow is not designed to hold back-and-forth conversations, so if you run into more questions that would be appropriate for this site, you can post a separate question and get some help there. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, If you refers points, then I would say col x & y together. So, I wanted to randomized only the last rows of 2 cols or the last points, not all of them. I thought modifying that for-loop would solve this issue. However, I have solved it in other way.  Thanks though!